# Angular JS not working in plunker

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I couldn't get my angular code to run in plunker. I have attached the details. Could any of you help me out? Basically it's a problem with ngcontroller I guess but I am not sure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    {{ 5 / 2 }}<br>
    {{message}}
  </body>

</html>
```

Contents of javascript script.js file

```
var MainController = function($scope){
  $scope.message = "Welcome!";
};
```

Plunk
http://plnkr.co/edit/mzgdELALCP7DN2ikJHsC?p=preview

Answer (score 8):

In version 1.3.*, you cannot longer declare a global controller function.

Instead define a module, and use your controller function:

```
var SidController = function($scope){

  $scope.message = "WElcome.";

};
SidController.$inject = ['$scope'];
angular.module('app', []).controller('SidController', SidController);
```

In your html

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VbO3L5PtiCO0JrAwBjf5?p=preview).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.. Well done on starting a tutorial! Simply replace the script in your index.html with

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I suppose the library Plunker currently has is outdated or something.

Answer (score 3):

Working [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FWti9DckbbcJFrZce9M2?p=preview) (with a different AngularJS version. @user3906922 has a better answer, where your version stays the same).

Use this for HTML for instance:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
 <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="SidController">

<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    {{ 5 / 2 }}<br>
{{message}}

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this plunkr
You need to define your module and then register the controller

http://plnkr.co/edit/9zAV5nSWH05FYscEWYZ5?p=preview

```
angular.module( 'demoApp', []);

angular.module( 'demoApp' )
    .controller( 'SidController', function($scope){
  $scope.message = "WElcome.";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create your module.

```
angular.module('app', []).controller("SidController", function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "WElcome.";
});
```

Then in your html element, set your attribute like this:

```
ng-app="app"
```